# combination of having count and column query

Tags: sql-server, join, having

I have a join table with a combined primary key of two columns. 
I want to query all entries

```
columnA having count > 1
```

and

```
columnB = value1 and value2
```

my query so far looks like this

```
select 
  columnA 
from tableA 
where columnB = 1 and 
columnA in (
         select 
           columnA 
         from tableA 
         group by columnA 
         having count(columnA) > 1)
```

or

```
select 
      columnA 
    from tableA 
    where columnB = 2 and 
    columnA in (
             select 
               columnA 
             from tableA 
             group by columnA 
             having count(columnA) > 1)
```

how can i query

```
...columnB = 1 and columnB = 2 and columnA in (select ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select columnA 
from tableA 
where columnB in (1,2)
group by columnA 
having count(distinct columnB) = 2
```

Having both values  `1` and `2` in `columnB` fullfills automatically `count(columnA) > 1`

If you want **either** the `columnB` condition (columnB having 2 values) **or** the `columnA` condition then do

```
select columnA 
from tableA 
group by columnA 
having count(*) > 1
or count(distinct columnB) = 2
```

or `columnB` must be `1` and `2`

```
select columnA 
from tableA 
group by columnA 
having count(*) > 1
or 
( 
   sum(case when columnB = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
   sum(case when columnB = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
)
```

Comment: thanks that works but what if i want to query count(columnA) = 2?

Comment: then add `and count(columnA) = 2` to the end.

Comment: but doesn't give me this also columnB combination (1,3) because column B in (1,2) is a or link isn't it?

Comment: Ok, if you want **either or** then you have to change it. See my update. It is actually now not so clear anymore what you really want.

Comment: your last one works finally with an "and" instead of "or"! thank you i had a rather ugly solution here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cec69/7